# Doing Validation on bootstrap nav tabs on change

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Usign AngularJS and bootsrap 3.I have 3 nav-tabs and with panels on them. How do i programatically prevent the tabs from changing to the next one if the user has not selected a customer or dvd's. On bot the customerSelect and dvdSelect tab's i have panel with a list where the user selects the customer anmd also a list of dvds.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active in"><a data-target="#customerSelect" data-toggle="tab">Customer</a></li>
            <li><a data-target="#dvdSelect" data-toggle="tab">Dvd List</a></li>
            <li><a data-target="#orderDetail" data-toggle="tab">Order Details</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="customerSelect">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dvdSelect">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="orderDetail">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have omitted much of the code within my tab content div's.

Comment: wrap a form within each tab-pane and check if its valid... (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery there are 4 different events for bootstrap tabs:

```
show.bs.tab // Occurs when the tab is about to be shown.    
shown.bs.tab  //  Occurs when the tab is fully shown (after CSS transitions have completed)  
hide.bs.tab // Occurs when the tab is about to be hidden   
hidden.bs.tab  // Occurs when the tab is fully hidden (after CSS transitions have completed)
```

A pseudo-example you could use:

```
$('.nav-tabs a').on('show.bs.tab', function(){
console.log('validation starts...');
if (correct!==true){
    $('#tab1').tab('show');
}else{
    $('#tab2').tab('show');
 }
});
```